# Gadfly: How to set number of sampling points when plotting functions?

Tags: julia, gadfly

When plotting a function (as opposed to numerical data), how can we set the number of sample points (i.e. the number of distinct *x* coordinates where the function is computed)?  Importantly, where can I find this information in the documentation?

Example:

```
plot(x -> sin(1/x), 0.001, 1)
```

[image: Plot with insufficient sampling]

For a useful plot in the 0–0.25 range we need many more points.

Comment: The code is [here](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/tree/master/src) so it _might_ be possible to find the relevant code? Perhaps adaptive plotting could be added, but Gadfly isn't always the only Julia plotting library around -- other solutions may be better at this...

Comment: @daycaster I found that `Plots.jl` has adaptive plotting since recently, so I removed that part. I am still interested in the main question, i.e. how to increase the number of sampling points.

Answer (score 4):

One way you can do it is:

```
using Gadfly;
X=1e-6:1e-6:1.0
plot(x=X, y=X .|> x -> sin(1/x), Geom.line)
```

or you may like this version more

```
using Gadfly;
X=[1/z for z=300.0:-0.05:1.0]
plot(x=X, y=X .|> x -> sin(1/x), Geom.line)
```

To get a docu, just do

```
?plot
```

or when you want to look at the code

```
methods(plot)
```

Comment: From your answer, I gather that there is no way to specify the number of sampling points.  `plot` is primarily for plotting numerical data, and the function syntax is just for convenience in the most basic use-cases. For anything more complicated we should compute the plot points manually (that's what you're doing).  Is this correct?

Comment: X (actually a range) is in the end a list of x-values. You may generate X in a way to be more dense when near 0 and less dense when near 1

Answer (score 2):

The number of sampling points can indeed be specified:

```
 plot(y=[x->sin(1/x)], xmin=[0.001], xmax=[1], Stat.func(1000), Geom.line)
```

You can find `Stat.func` in the Gadfly docs here:
http://gadflyjl.org/stable/lib/statistics/#Gadfly.Stat.func.

Note you can write either `Stat.func(num_samples=1000)` or `Stat.func(1000)`, since there is only one argument.